# How to sql query that depends on field in row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, yii2

I have mysql table `Vegetables` with fields `price` and `unit`. Unit can be `1` or `2`, it means kilogram (`1`) or ton (`2`). It is unit weight. Price depends on unit, so `price=200` with `unit=1` is less then `price=20` with `unit=2`, because 1 ton = 1000 kilogram

**Q**: I have query like `... ORDER BY 'price' ACS`. How to make order by `price` that depends on `unit` field of the same table?
Just no idea how to do that..

On words it is like `... ORDER BY {if(this.unit==1):price;else:price*1000} ACS`

I am using yii2 for this project: `Vegetable::find()->addOrderBy('price asc');`

Comment: post your code fragment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Vegetables
ORDER BY IF(unit=1,price,price*1000) ACS
```

Comment: or,  `ORDER BY price*POWER(1000,unit-1)`,  The more ANSI standard compliant alternative would be `ORDER BY price * CASE WHEN unit=1 THEN 1 ELSE 1000 END`